# How to register new application for Instagram?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm trying to create an Android app that uses Instagram API. I am required to register a new application on Instagram website to obtain the client id, client secret etc. but it asks me for something called OAuth redirect_uri. I'm not familiar with what that is and how to obtain one. I don't have a website and this OAuth redirect_uri is required at registration. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect uri is the uri (usually a url) to where Instagram will redirect you to after you enter your login details.

So in your WebView once you enter login credentials, it goes to the redirect_uri with added parameters based on whether the login was successful or not.

Since you're on Android though, you need to get these parameters from your webview somehow. What you can do is something like this:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith(REDIRECT_URI)) {
                    // Get parameters
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    String problem = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_problem");
                    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                    // Do stuff, then maybe call some method to close the webview
                } else
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

What should your redirect uri be? I'm not sure, but all valid URIs I've tried seem to work.
You should probably make it unique to your app, like `com-example-myapp://instagramredirect`